# Sit Down and Shut Up

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> You can drive me, play me or take me
>   But don't contemporaneously
>   Laterally, I am B through Z
>   
>   Whatever the case, please take your seat
>   And have a listen, or fall asleep
>   But above all, identify me.

**Hint**

> By now, you must have seen
>  Begotten by pen or machine
>  Several things share my name
>  Stop calling me a bus

Comment: When your answer is so bad that OP has to change the puzzle.

Comment: I didn't *change* it per se, just added a hint ;)

Comment: I lost it at "Stop calling me a bus"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can drive me, play me or take me

> You can drive a Hyundai Sonata, play a sonata (maybe Mozart), or take the drug zaleplon, known commercially as Sonata

But don't contemporaneously

> Yeah, playing a sonata and driving at the same time is dicey enough, but definitely don't do that under the effects of a sleeping pill.

Laterally, I am B through Z

> It's Sooooo not A

Whatever the case, please take your seat
And have a listen, or fall asleep

> Sit in the car, listen to a sonata, or fall asleep from the effects of the pill

But above all, identify me.

> You a sonata dogg

Comment: don't forget! most importantly, it's not a bus, haha

Answer (score 9):

I think the answer is

> NOTA

You can drive me, play me or take me
But don't contemporaneously

> [Nota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota), the car company. [Nota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%B3ta), a song. [Nota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/None_of_the_above), a ballot choice

Laterally, I am B through Z

> B to Z  = Not A

Whatever the case, please take your seat

> The car company reference.

And have a listen, or fall asleep

> The song reference.

But above all, identify me.

> Above all refer to None Of The **Above**

By now, you must have seen
Begotten by pen or machine
Several things share my name

> Last line suggests that None Of The Above shares my name.

Comment: This is the closest answer yet. I wouldn't want to fall asleep on account of a song, though

Comment: @Matt [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KbauuM9EhY)

Comment: Ah, no way you .. won't ... zzzzzzzzz

Answer (score 7):

I am:

> Not a bus

Reasoning:

> The hint says: "Stop calling me a bus"

"Laterally, I am B through Z"

> Sounds like "I am not a bus". The "s" is soft.

Comment: well ... uhh ... but ... ah, just take your upvote.

Comment: I'll call that a win.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is:

> train. You can drive a train, play with model trains and take a train. Wouldn't do those at the same time, as it's not safe. Not sure about the B through to Z, but it rhymes with name in the hint. People go Train spotting to identify the trains, you can listen to the announcers and take a seat/nap on them :)

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the answer I'm looking for. Welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: Thank you! Oh well :) Yeah the B - Z makes no sense for this answer haha

Answer (score 5):

You are

> A bus

You can drive me, play me or take me
 But don't contemporaneously

> Drive a bus, take the bus, or play ride the bus (Drinking Game), but don't do them at them same time because you can't ride and drive at the same time, and also you can't drink and drive

Laterally, I am B through Z

> Not sure, Possibly 25 rows on an average bus

Whatever the case, please take your seat
 And have a listen, or fall asleep

> Stay seated and listen to music or take a nap

But above all, identify me.

> You're a bus

Comment: Sorry, not the answer. "You're a bus" made me chuckle, though.

Comment: Sit down and shut up just sounds like something every bus driver has said at one point in their careers

Comment: Probably, but as a bus commuter, I've never heard it. No one says anything, ever. Silence.

Comment: I would contest that driving the bus, is, in fact riding the bus, unless you're doing it remotely.  Also, you *can* drink and drive, though you shouldn't.

Comment: well to be fair it doesn't say you cant contemporaneously, it says don't contemporaneously. And I respectfully disagree with your ride/drive perspective

Answer (score 5):

> A USB Flash Drive.

You can drive me, play me or take me

But don't contemporaneously

> One access its content as a drive or via the auto-play dialog. Otherwise, one would be carrying it in his pockets. But you can't do all simultaneously.

Laterally, I am B through Z

> Usually, a USB drive is labeled B to Z (A being reserved to floppy disk drives)

Whatever the case, please take your seat

And have a listen, or fall asleep

> Whatever you choose to do, you'll be using me.

But above all, identify me.

> Make sure the USB drive is recognized by the computer.

By now, you must have seen

Begotten by pen or machine

> Referring to newer technologies that has taken its place. Like a USB pen with storage.

Several things share my name

Stop calling me a bus

> USB can mean a flash drive or the port. "bus" refers to USB being an abbreviated form of Universal Serial **Bus**

Comment: Sorry, but no. The bus hint just refers to the first answer, which was a bus

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is:

> A note

Reasoning:
You can drive me, play me or take me

> You can drive a note (sing) or more fitting is the Nissan Versa Note, play a note (music), take a note (take notes like in class)

But don't contemporaneously

> These things probably won't happen at the same time

Laterally, I am B through Z

> No idea on this one

Whatever the case, please take your seat

> You should probably sit to take notes, or play music

And have a listen, or fall asleep

> You can listen to music or fall asleep, same with lectures where you could take notes

But above all, identify me.

> Identifying musical notes is important for musicians

Hint:

> By now, you must have seen
>  Begotten by pen or machine
>  -Notes can be taken on laptops or by hand
>  Several things share my name
>  -Musical note, notes written, to note something (similar to written)
>  Stop calling me a bus
>  -Answer is not a bus

Comment: If you picked the kind of note you can *actually* drive, you would be a lot closer. Still, not the intended answer, though